# Compiling ada library gnatcoll-json.adb with gnat on OS/X

Tags: json, macos, ada, gnat

I've got the source from `Adacore`, so it should work - I've left an 'issue' on Adacore as well, but it might take some time to get a resolution there. I suspect that I might be doing something wrong, any suggestions?

Here's the problem:

```
$ gnat make gnatcoll-json.adb

    gcc -c gnatcoll-json.adb

    gnatcoll-json.adb:33:23: missing body for "Prepend" declared at gnatcoll-json.ads:64

    gnatcoll-json.adb:33:23: missing body for "Create" declared at gnatcoll-json.ads:99

    gnatcoll-json.adb:33:23: missing body for "Set_Field" declared at gnatcoll-json.ads:144

    gnatcoll-json.adb:33:23: missing body for "Get" declared at gnatcoll-json.ads:173

    gnatcoll-json.adb:33:23: missing body for "Get" declared at gnatcoll-json.ads:206

    gnatcoll-json.adb:454:63: prefix of dereference must be an access type

    gnatcoll-json.adb:641:33: invalid operand types for operator "/="    gnatcoll-json.adb:641:33: left operand has private type "UTF8_Unbounded_String" defined at gnatcoll-json.ads:47

    gnatcoll-json.adb:641:33: right operand has an access type

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:19: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:28: expected type "Counter" defined at gnatcoll-json.ads:239

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:28: found private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:28:   ==> in call to "Free" at gnatcoll-json.ads:289

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:28:   ==> in call to "Free" at gnatcoll-json.ads:287

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:28:   ==> in call to "Free" at gnatcoll-json.ads:285

    gnatcoll-json.adb:642:28:   ==> in call to "Free" at a-strunb.ads:88

    gnatcoll-json.adb:714:24: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"

    gnatcoll-json.adb:714:24: found type access to "UTF8_String" defined at line 714

    gnatcoll-json.adb:841:28: prefix of dereference must be an access type

    gnatmake: "gnatcoll-json.adb" compilation error
```

I can see that those **missing bodies** in the `gnatcoll.ads` file seem to be the first problem. It's certainly true that, for example, the body of **Prepend** isn't in that file - but I thought that the body should be in the `gnatcoll.adb` file, not the `gnatcoll.ads` file anyway.

Comment: your description references gnatcoll.ad[sb] but your compilation is of gnatcoll-json.ad[sb] can you clarify if the missing bodies are in gnatcoll-json.adb ? also , are the gnatcoll.ad[sb] files also in the current directory ?

Answer (score 0):

`GNATColl` is intended to be built using a fairly standard `configure`/`make`/`make install` process. You can find out more by looking at `docs/building.rst` in the distribution; I don't have the [`Sphinx` program](http://sphinx-doc.org/) that is used to build the installable version, but it's pretty readable as-is. There's also `docs/json.rst` to tell you how to use the JSON support once `GNATColl` is installed.

In the root directory of the distribution,

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/your/preferred/install/location # default is /usr/local
$ make
$ sudo make install # if /your/preferred/install/location isn't user-writable
```